# Root within square root symbol

Tags: math-mode

how can I avoid that the following expression

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=14pt]{scrbook}  
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    a = \sqrt[m]{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}^m}.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

is displayed in this form ($m$ is cut by the root symbol):

[image]

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Try to use `\sqrt[m\,]{\sum...}.`

Comment: please make a complete document that produces that display and post, the input shown would set the summation in inline style not with the limits above and below.

Comment: That is not possible with standard LaTeX math mode. So do what David said!

Comment: Sorry for not posting the full code. Now I think, the problem might be the lmodern package in combination with the 14pt fontsize.

Comment: And the m\, does help!

Comment: @AnkaiosArgo Thanks for fixing the question, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the usual problem due to the setting of the math extension font done by `lmodern.sty`, which defines `OMX/lmex/m/n` for it with this *completely wrong* font definition file:

```
\ProvidesFile{omxlmex.fd}[2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern]

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{lmex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{lmex}{m}{n}{%
   <->sfixed*lmex10%
   }{}
\endinput
```

This means that `lmex10` is used no matter what the surrounding font size is. This *might* seem to work at standard sizes (it doesn't, however, try with `\sum` in a subscript).

I usually suggest to reinstate the Computer Modern math extension font, but applying the fact that nowadays arbitrary scaling is possible.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=14pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{%
  <-7.5>cmex7
  <7.5-8.5>cmex8
  <8.5-9.5>cmex9
  <9.5->cmex10
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}


\begin{document}
\[
a = \sqrt[m]{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}^m}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem! If you have some additinal time, would be nice, if you could explain, how you came up with the numbers.

Comment: @AnkaiosArgo The figures in the `\DeclareFontShape` command are based on the available optical sizes for `cmex`; if the requested size is around 7pt (or below, for second level sub/superscripts), use cmex7; if it is around 8pt, use cmex8 and so on; `cmex10` is the largest size available, so from 9.5pt up there's no other choice.

Answer (score 10):

Something strange in the lmodern font metrics it appears.

You can shift the index with `\leftroot`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=14pt]{scrbook}  
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    a = \sqrt[\leftroot{2}m]{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}^m}.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Original computer modern answer:

The input you show would use an inline style unlike the image shown, and display style should not over print the index Please always post a complete document that shows the problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$a = \sqrt[m]{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}^m}$

\[
a = \sqrt[m]{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}^m}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David! The leftroot is a nice workaround. However, it seems to be better to solve the problem at the "root". Thus I think egreg's solutions is the way to go.

Comment: @AnkaiosArgo you made an old man very happy: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16249651#16249651

Comment: how ones avoid that ugly **square sqrt** in the centered case?

Comment: @janmarqz a font only has a few fixed sizes of root symbols then has to use an extendible vertical rule, so that is how it is.

Comment: sad!... thank you David