# Typesetting nth roots when n is long

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Trying to take the `nm`th root of `a` results in `nm` overflowing off the radical sign. How can I extend the "tail" of the radical sign to contain all of `nm`?

[image: The $nm$th root of $a$.]

Answers to similar questions suggest using the amsmath package to adjust the placement of `nm`, but `nm` is too long to fit in the space provided.

Comment: Maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186341/root-within-square-root-symbol has a solution for you?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, Merry christmas.

Comment: I believe, that radicals are often converted to exponents, when they are more than just a constant.

Comment: You don't. Nobody does.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen, you're right, but the full context is `$\sqrt[m]{ \sqrt[n]{a} } = \sqrt[nm]{a} $`. I'm just trying to show a property of radicals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this (`\leftroot{-6}\uproot{6}`) will helps:

```
\sqrt[\leftroot{-6}\uproot{6}nm]{a}
```